# How to Deploy Click Once Application in different Domains

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce, publishing, setup-deployment

I have built a C# WPF Application in Dot Net Framework 3.0 and published thru Click Once Application via localhost IIS in my system. My system placed in FileServer1 Domain and all the systems under FileServer1 can able to install the application. But we can not able to install it under different domain FileServer2.

While clicking the Install button, it will show that Installation file was missing. Please help me out how to proceed with this issue.

Comment: file permissions? Hardcoded path to FileServer1 as "installation" url? your question is very vague and we can't help you until you provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While publishing the file, I have given as http:\10.xxx.xx.xx instead of localhost. Now its working in all the domains.